# In Scala, apply function to values for some keys in immutable map

Tags: scala, collections

Let an immutable map

```
val m = (0 to 3).map {x => (x,x*10) }.toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 20, 3 -> 30)
```

a collection of keys of interest

```
val k = Set(0,2)
```

and a function

```
def f(i:Int) = i + 1
```

How to apply `f` onto the values in the map mapped by the keys of interest so that the resulting map would be

```
Map(0 -> 1, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 21, 3 -> 30)
```

Comment: you have an immutable map, why do you want to mutate it? You could do: `(m.keySet intersect k).map(e => (e -> f(e)).toMap`?

Comment: @S.R.I your solution produces
    `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 1, 2 -> 3)`

Comment: @goral, yes and adding other keys from the map is another triviality. :-)

Comment: @goral, hint: you can use `diff` and `map` on sets.

Comment: @goral, that said: your output looks incorrect - If you apply `f` onto that Map `m`, you'd be getting `Map(0->1, 1 -> 10, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 30)`. Not what you've shown.

Comment: If you're feeling super golfy (not recommended!): `m ++ k.flatMap(x => m.get(x).map(x -> f(_)))`, or if you "know" `k` only contains keys in `m` (even less recommended!): `m ++ k.map(x => x -> f(m(x)))`.

Comment: No @S.R.I., srry... My answer can't be wrong cause it was copied directly from REPL

Comment: Oh, right.. Now that i read your question again, i was working by keys than values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
m.transform{ (key, value) => if (k(key)) f(value) else value }
```

Comment: I think if you're using `transform` and not `map`, it would make sense to do `m.transform { (key, value) if k(key) => f(value) }`...? Otherwise you're always just replacing every pair anyway and might as well use `map`.

Comment: Your snippet does not compile. I guess you meant `case (key, value)`, right? This won't work either because `transform` does not exepect a `PartialFunction`. As for the fact that you can as well use `map`, well yes, that's for sure. The only gain from using `transform` is not to have to repeat the key in the return value.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I assumed `transform` does indeed take a `PartialFunction` as it does in some JSON and XML libraries... my bad.

Answer (score 1):

That's the first thing that popped into my mind but I am pretty sure that in Scala you could do it prettier:

```
m.map(e =>  {
    if(k.contains(e._1)) (e._1 -> f(e._2)) else (e._1 -> e._2)
})
```

Comment: This is a little bit shorter as the expression in the else branch is just e: m.map(e =>  {
    if(k.contains(e._1)) (e._1 -> f(e._2)) else e
})

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @regis-jean-gilles answer using `map` and pattern matching

```
m.map { case a @ (key, value) => if (k(key)) key -> f(value) else a }
```